# Replace specific file in a zip file using java

Tags: java, zip, java.nio.file

I would like to replace a specific file (README.MD) in prj-basics-final.zip with the external file of the same name.
The code below doesn't replace README.MD in prj-basics-final.zip. It doesn't throw any error also.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class UpdateZipFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path zipFilePath = Paths.get("/Users/pradeepjonnalagadda/ZipFile/prj-basics-final.zip");
        Path externalFile = Paths.get("/Users/pradeepjonnalagadda/ZipFile/README.md");;
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipFilePath, null);
            Path fileInsideZipPath = fs.getPath("/README.md");
            Files.copy(externalFile, fileInsideZipPath,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 
            System.out.println("Finished processing");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you would need to unzip it first, replace, and then zip it back?

Comment: @Andreas.Unziping and adding is a time consuming process and this seems to be the way to directly replace without opening it.

Comment: Well on the other hand, that did not work. So, maybe try another way?